# Не работает переход с одного активити в другую

Tags: java, android

Учусь разрабатывать приложение.
Цель: сделать переход с раскрывающегося меню на кнопку и активити "Настройки".
Проблема: при нажатии кнопки "Настройки", приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

> Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer @3647df65, destroying layer...

menu_main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Настройки"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/about_app"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="О приложении"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_exit"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="Выход"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
```

MainActivity:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    TextView headerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.about_app) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, about_app.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
};
```

UPD: Поменял оператор на Case, всё равно вылет+такой длиннющий лог ошибки.

```
  11-29 18:18:27.156 2581-2581/com.memes.yakutian E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.memes.yakutian, PID: 2581
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.memes.yakutian.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2970)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:407)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:63)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1194)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3240)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4191)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5667)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:962)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: В приведённом коде ошибки не видать. В приведённом логе - тоже. Попробуйте выложить полный лог ошибки и код+разметку активити настроек

Comment: Сделано. Поменял оператор с if на case, всё равно ошибки и вылеты.

Comment: Собственно у вас ошибка приведения типов в строчке, которая ничего не делает) Удалите `TextView headerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` и ошибка исчезнет) Ну или кастуйте к правильному типу так `Toolbar headerView = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`

Comment: Да, тоже заметил когда разбирал ошибки) Спасибо Юрий, если бы не вы, я бы не смог заметить эту строку в логе. Жалко, что пол дня на это потратил из-за одной ненужной строки(

Comment: Это наоборот хорошо) Только на таких ошибках и боли от потраченного на них времени появляется желание не оставлять лишних строк в коде и следить за всем происходящим)

Comment: @SeregaFilippov странно что вы видели ошибку и не стали её читать, там же все написано: `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`